# ASP.NET MVC One Website Running on Two Different Ports

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2019

I have this weird issue on Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. I am running an ASP.NET MVC 5 solution with only one project. The problem is every time I run it, sometimes one port is running fine, sometimes it is not.

Here is the screenshot of my IIS Express:

[image]

As you can see, it's only under one site and is showing multiple ports. I am not running any service, only website from ASP.NET MVC. It's erratic on my part since sometimes, one port is working, the other is not. So I need to relaunch multiple times my solution so that I can debug properly.

I already changed my port on my solution, but the first one is only reflecting on my edit, the other one, I cannot find a way how to edit the port or remove it totally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already figured it out. I just disabled the https port, and debugging my ASP.NET solution was smooth afterwards. To disable https, go to Solution explorer, select your project and press `F4` on your keyboard, to see the settings:

[image]

If during debugging, you notice that your debugger shutsdown erratically make sure of the following as well:

- Seperate your browser tab to your debugging browser tab
- Since if you try to remove your debugging browser tab to other tabs, VS 2019 Community Edition debugging shutsdown unexpectedly. It happens on my Microsoft Edge browsers even on Chrome.
- So seperate then and you are good to go